# Regex to match Pipe symbol between commas with no string text between

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I am looking to match ONLY single pipes between commas that have no text leading or trailing it. I have tried looking online and cannot find the exact regex for this. I am new to regex and would love some help.

For example:

```
5,|,|,|,|,0.0|0.0,a,a,|a|||a||||||||,,,,,
```

I would only like the four pipe symbol between the commas to be matched.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I am using JAVA regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<=,)\|(?=,)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2y3Df/1/)